# Sorting and ranking subsets of complex data

Tags: python, subset, arcgis, ranking

I have a large and complex GIS-datafile on road accidents in “cities" within “counties”. Rows represent roads. Columns provide “City”, “County” and "Sum of accidents in city”. A city thus contains several roads (repeated values of accident sums) and a county several cities. 
For each 'County', I now want to rank cities according to the number of accidents, so that within each 'County', the city with most accidents is ranked “1" and cities with fewer accidents are ranked “2” and above. This rank-value shall be written into the original datafile.

My original approach was to:
 1. Sort data according to "'County'_ID" and “Accidents” (descending)
 2. than calculate for each row:

```
if('County' in row 'n+1' = 'County' in row ’n’) AND (Accidents in row 'n+1' = 'Accidents' in row ’n’): 
    return value: ’n’  ## maintain same rank for cities within 'County'

else if ('County' in row 'n+1' = 'County' in row ’n’) AND if ('Accidents' in row 'n+1' < 'Accidents' in row ’n’): 
    return value: ’n+1’  ## increasing rank value  within 'County'

else if ('County' in row 'n+1' < 'County' in row ’n’) AND ('Accidents' in row 'n+1’ < 'Accidents' in row ’n’): 
    return value:’1’  ## new 'County', i.e. start ranking from 1

else:  
    return “0” #error
```

However, I could not figure out how to code this properly; and maybe this approach is not an appropriate way either; maybe a loop would do the trick?

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using Python [Pandas module](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/index.htm)

**Fictitious Data**

*Create Data with columns county, accidents, city*

Would use [pandas read_csv](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-read-csv) to load actual data.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 1, 'A'],
    ['a', 2, 'B'],
    ['a', 5, 'C'],
    ['b', 5, 'D'],
    ['b', 5, 'E'],
    ['b', 6, 'F'],
    ['b', 8, 'G'],
    ['c', 2, 'H'],
    ['c', 2, 'I'],
    ['c', 7, 'J'],
    ['c', 7, 'K']
], columns = ['county', 'accidents', 'city'])
```

*Resultant Dataframe*

df:

```
  county  accidents city
0       a          1    A
1       a          2    B
2       a          5    C
3       b          5    D
4       b          5    E
5       b          6    F
6       b          8    G
7       c          2    H
8       c          2    I
9       c          7    J
10      c          7    K
```

*Group data rows by county, and [rank](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-rank/) rows within group by accidents*

**Ranking Code**

```
# ascending = False causes cities with most accidents to be ranked = 1
df["rank"] = df.groupby("county")["accidents"].rank("dense", ascending=True)
```

*Result*

df:

```
  county  accidents city  rank
0       a          1    A   3.0
1       a          2    B   2.0
2       a          5    C   1.0
3       b          5    D   3.0
4       b          5    E   3.0
5       b          6    F   2.0
6       b          8    G   1.0
7       c          2    H   2.0
8       c          2    I   2.0
9       c          7    J   1.0
10      c          7    K   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach by @DarryIG is correct, but it doesn't consider that the environment is ArcGIS.

Since you tagged your question with `Python` I came up with a workflow utilizing Pandas. There are other ways to do the same, using ArcGIS tools and or the Field Calculator.

```py
import arcpy # if you are using this script outside ArcGIS
import pandas as pd 

# change this to your actual shapefile, you might have to include a path
filename = "road_accidents" 
sFields = ['County', 'City', 'SumOfAccidents'] # consider this to be your columns

# read everything in your file into a Pandas DataFrame with a SearchCursor
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(filename, sFields) as sCursor:
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[row for row in sCursor], columns=field_names)
df = df.drop_duplicates() # since each row represents a street, we can remove duplicate
# we use this code from DarrylG to calculate a rank
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('County')['SumOfAccidents'].rank('dense', ascending=True)
# set a multiindex, since there might be duplicate city-names
df = df.set_index(['County', 'City'])
dct = df.to_dict() # convert the dataframe into a dictionary

# add a field to your shapefile
arcpy.AddField_management('Rank', 'Rank', 'SHORT')

# now we can update the Shapefile
uFields = ['County', 'City', 'Rank']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(filename, uFields) as uCursor: # open a UpdateCursor on the file
    for row in uCursor: # for each row (street)
        # get the county/city combo
        County_City = (row[uFields.index('County')], row[uFields.index('City')])
        if County_City in dct: # see if it is in your dictionary (it should)
            # give it the value from dictionary
            row[uFields.index('Rank')] = dct['Rank'][County_City] 
        else: 
            # otherwise...
            row[uFields.index('Rank')] = 999
        uCursor.updateRow(row) # update the row
```

You can run this code inside ArcGIS Pro Python console. Or using Jupyter Notebooks. Hope it helps!